# Loosing UDP messages during routing?

Tags: networking, routing, wireshark, winsock

I am trying to test software that I’ve written to send UDP messages. This software works if I don’t bind the socket to a port (i.e. it defaults to NIC 1). I can see the messages with Wireshark running on the PC.  However, if I bind the IP socket to NIC 2 (with the static IP address) Wireshark does not sniff any UDP packets for 192.168.1.100.  Originally I thought there was an issue with my software, but I tested on another PC setup and it works as expected.

This leads me to think that there is a routing issue, but I am stumped.

Setup:
PC (Windows 10) physically directly connected to a FPGA with static IP 192.168.1.100.  The PC has two NICs: (a) an on board NIC with a auto-configured IP address 192.168.55.XXX and (2) an external NIC configured with a static IP 192.168.1.125 and jumbo frames enabled.

Things I have tried:

1. Same software on different PCs: works as expected.
2. Flushing the routing table
3. Pinging 192.168.1.100 -> result is
   `Pinging 192.168.1.100 with 32 bytes of data:`
   `Reply from 209.53.192.YYY: Destination host unreachable.`
4. Update routing table via `route ADD`: several different routes to the table (destination 192.168.1.0 and 192.168.1.100). No change in results
   [route print][1]
5. Update routing table with `netsh`
6. tracert 192.168.1.100

   ```
     1 <1 ms   <1 ms   <1 ms  192.168.55.NNN
     2     1 ms    1 ms    1 ms  207.216.41.VVV
     3     4 ms    1 ms    1 ms  96.1.221.ZZZ
     4     1 ms    1 ms    1 ms  209.53.192.YYY
     5  209.53.192.YYY  reports: Destination host unreachable.
   ```
7. Ensure everything is started in admin mode
8. Move the ethernet cable and static IP to the onboard NIC. Same behavior
9. Replaced FPGA with another PC configured with an IP address. Same behavior.
10. Ping from the second PC (see above): ping 192.168.1.125 (in the other direction) is successful

Other Comments:

1. In desired configuration, only related messages seen on Wireshark are:   `ARP    42    Who has 192.168.1.100? Tell 192.168.1.125`
2. My software is written in C++ and using winsock

I feel like I am missing something simple.... TIA
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mnmj.png

Comment: Try adding a route like `route add 192.168.1.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.100 METRIC 3 IF X` where `X` is the interface number listed in `route print`. The important part is this route's metric needs to be lower than your default gateway (tracert shows it's currently taking the default route out). Then try pinging again, and maybe run `arp -a` to see if your PC got a reply from the connected device. Once the routing is fixed, the automatic bind should work fine

Comment: Thanks, but no dice. I now have `192.168.1.0  255.255.255.0  192.168.1.100  192.168.1.125  28` in the table.  I'm surprised the metric is 28, as I used your suggestion of 3. I didnt know the gateway should be 192.168.1.100, as I thought the gateway should have the address of the NIC (although I had tried this IP several times). I had read On-link was okay for devices that are directly connected, but Id believe that is wrong. I'm surprised that apr -a shows: `Interface: 192.168.1.125 - 0x7
Internet Address  Physical Address  Type
192.168.1.111   c0-25-e9-0f-dd-25 dynamic`

Comment: yep the gateway doesn't matter much for directly connected devices. If you have an arp entry for 192.168.1.111, I'd suspect the fpga has picked up that address (unless there's another device connected to that interface?). Do you get a response from `ping 192.168.1.111` or the broadcast `ping 192.168.1.255`

Comment: Thanks for confirming the gateway question.  I have been trying to get this to work for days, so at some point I set the static IP to `192.168.1.111` and then back to `192.168.1.125`.  When I ping my PC from the second PC, I only get a response for `ping 192.168.1.111`.  I feel like this wasn't the case a day or so ago.... but I can't be sure.

Comment: It sounds like the new route is working then? Or maybe you need to clarify which PC has what IP/arp table/symptoms again

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I can only ping from PC2 to PC1 (`ping 192.168.1.111` works, despite the routing table thinking the IF is 192.168.1.125). I need to make sure I can send messages the other way (from 192.168.1.125 *to* 192.168.1.100).

Comment: Try and flush your routes again > set nic2 to dhcp > then back to static `192.168.1.125` and make sure the routes show up okay (may need to set the suggested metric again). Then try pinging from both ends. Another thing you can check is the saved next-hop cache: `netsh interface ip show destinationcache [address=192.168.1.100]` and optionally flush that too with `netsh interface ip delete destinationcache`

Comment: I was hopeful this would work, but I still get `Reply from 209.53.192.169: Destination host unreachable.` when I ping 192.168.1.100, even after changing the metric to 33.  I don't know what 209.53 is....

Comment: The 209 IP is your internet provider, which is responding because your ping packets are being directed out to the internet. What interface shows up when you run `netsh interface ip show destinationcache address=192.168.1.100`?

Comment: There isn't anything, it's blank when I call that